# Kernel switching when kexec has been disabled

Tags: linux-kernel, kexec

Is it possible to switch another kernel in grub's boot menu if you had disabled the `kexec()-syscall` in the kernel config `kernel.kexec_load_disabled = 1` ?

Comment: Your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Y: is it possible to change kernel when I disabled kexec() (hint: GRUB is not the Linux kernel, it's unrelated)? I guess X could be: can I programatically change the next kernel to boot after reboot? Can you confirm what's your actual intention by asking this question? Please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/746606/edit) your question to clarify the goal.